# Как заполнить столбцы в таблице на основе столбцов из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как можно заполнить столбец одной (`t1`) таблицы из таблицы (`t2`) таким образом:
если столбец `t1.id = t2.id`, то столбец таблицы `t1.name` будет заполнен из таблицы `t2.name`.
То есть, строки столбца `name` зависят от строк столбца `id`.
Значения `id` конечно же уникальны, а `name` повторяются.

На словах просто, на деле пока не могу понять как решить.

Конечно про `UPDATE` знаю, и поэтому этот способ опускаем. Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: почитай про merge into

Answer (score 3):

> Конечно про `UPDATE` знаю, и поэтому этот способ опускаем. Есть ли другой способ?

Есть, [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F). Конечно, его следует использовать, только когда в этом есть необходимость.

Вот [рабочий пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=772aec239fa8b7dbec5a4f3d63187e79) с полной синхронизацией таблицы `t1` из таблицы источника `t2`:

```sql
create table t1 as 
    select rownum id, 'name '||rownum name from dual connect by level<=3
/    
create table t2 as select * from t1
/
```

Сейчас обе таблицы точные копии друг друга. Изменим их, затем выполним `MERGE`:

```sql
delete t2 where id=3;
update t2 set name='*'||name;
insert into t2 values (4, '*name 4');  
insert into t1 values (5, 'name 5');  

merge into t1 using (
    select coalesce (t2.id, t1.id) id, coalesce (t2.name, 'deleted') name
    from t2 full join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
) src on (src.id = t1.id)
when not matched then 
    insert values (src.id, src.name)
when matched then 
    update set t1.name = src.name
    delete where src.name = 'deleted'
/
```

Результат последнего - таблица `t1` вновь стала точной копией `t2`:

```sql
(select * from t1 minus select * from t2) union all
(select * from t2 minus select * from t1);

no rows selected
```